# Comprobar diferencias de dos array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Estoy tratando de comprobar la diferencia de dos array para insertar o borrar datos en MySQL pero el código que tengo falla muchísimo y lo mismo hay otra forma de hacerlo más adecuada, pero no la conozco.

El código del comparador y la función para borrar es éste:

```
$Diferencia = array_udiff(
    $Todo,
    $EnFormulario,
    function($a, $b) { //compruebo las diferencias en ambos array para saber que borrar y que agregar
        if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
            return 0;
        } // Si es igual
        return -1;
    }
);

if (count($Diferencia) >= 1) {
    foreach($Diferencia as $BorrarCod) {
        $BorrarCodigos = Borrar_Datos(
            "Direcciones" ,
            "id",
            "".$BorrarCod["id"].""
        );
    }
} //borro lo que ya no exista y cierro el count
```

Por otro lado tengo dos consultas a MySQL que generan los dos array a comparar que serían éstos:

```
$Todo = Consulta_Dinamica(
    "Array",
    "*",
    "Direcciones",
    "`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '" . $_POST["art_nuevo"] . "' "
);

$EnFormulario = [];
foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUpColorTalli) {
    $EnFormulario[] = Consulta_Dinamica(
        "Simple",
        "*",
        "Direcciones",
        "`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '" . $_POST["art_nuevo"] .
            "' AND `1`='" . $DUpColorTalli['tallas'] .
            "' AND `2`='" . $DUpColorTalli['color'] . "' "
    );
}
```

En `$Todo` consulto todos los datos y los almaceno en un array. 
En la variable `$EnFormulario` lo que hago es una consulta simple y almaceno en esa misma variable el resultado (o eso creo que hago).

Los datos que me devuelven los dos array son estos:

```
    $Todo 
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1112
                [que] => Codigo
                [idcosa] => 80
                [1] => 129
                [2] => 40
                [3] => 843446300048
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1113
                [que] => Codigo
                [idcosa] => 80
                [1] => 36
                [2] => 40
                [3] => 843446300049
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1114
                [que] => Codigo
                [idcosa] => 80
                [1] => 129
                [2] => 87
                [3] => 843446300050
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1115
                [que] => Codigo
                [idcosa] => 80
                [1] => 36
                [2] => 87
                [3] => 843446300051
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
            )

    )

$Enformulario
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1112
                [id] => 1112
                [1] => 129
                [que] => Codigo
                [2] => 40
                [idcosa] => 80
                [3] => 843446300048
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
                [11] => 
                [12] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1113
                [id] => 1113
                [1] => 36
                [que] => Codigo
                [2] => 40
                [idcosa] => 80
                [3] => 843446300049
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
                [11] => 
                [12] => 
            )
```

He probado a poner un array_diff simple pero no me devuelve ningún resultado a pesar que entre $Todo y $Enformulario tienen cambios evidentes...

Realmente solo necesito que me borre lo que este en $Todo que ya no este en $Enformulario

Comment: En que falla el `array_diff` ? Puedes agregar que contiene el arreglo1 y el arreglo2?

Comment: ¿Entiendes que funciona en ambos sentidos y que tu código espera que en los datos del formulario haya un array cuyos elementos tengan un índice 'id' con el que comparar con los elementos del array original (que también deben tenerlo)? ¿Podrías poner un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) con datos en `$Todo` y `$EnFormulario`? Puedes usar `var_dump`, `var_export` o `serialize` (**`var_export($Todo); var_export($EnFormulario);`**) justo antes de `array_udiff` para mostrarnos los datos de ambas variables para tratar de reproducir tu problema.

Comment: No es más fácil hacerlo directamente con SQL. **DELETE FROM tablaA INNER JOIN tablaB ON tablaA.id = tablaB.id
USING tablaA**. Cuidado al ejecutar la consulta no vaya a ser que borres algún registro que no debes

Comment: @Xerif parece que está comparando datos de la base de datos con lo que hay en un formulario (o eso dice) que genera elementos en `$UpTallicolor`. Sin saber cómo se genera esa variable no puedes saber si hay forma directa de comprar por SQL las diferencias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia  La verdad, no queda claro del todo realmente, pero entiendo que lo que compara son registros de dos tablas, por lo que pienso que en una sola consulta podría ser viable. Aún que tenga un formulario para establecer el WHERE.

Comment: @Killpe, ¿pudiste leer nuestros comentarios? ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la información que te solicitamos para poder ayudarte? Gracias :)

Comment: @OscarGarcia si, acabo de agregar lo que me devuelve los array...

Comment: @OscarGarcia Mil gracias Oscar :)

Comment: Con algunos cambios he logrado reproducir tu código, pero no veo nada extraño en su funcionamiento. Este es el resultado: https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/9b4a3bb4dbef24cc481b046182520781 ¿qué es lo que no te funciona? ¿cuál es el comportamiento que esperas con estos datos? PD: Acabo de ver el texto "Realmente solo necesito que me borre lo que este en $Todo que ya no este en $Enformulario" en lo que has editado. Voy a responderte.

Comment: @OscarGarcia que no siempre funciona... en ocasiones meto datos nuevos y borro otros del formulario y se vuelve loco y lo borra prácticamente todo.

Comment: En mi respuesta te explico el motivo. Espero que te sea de ayuda. Tal y como te he puesto en el otro comentario: si necesitas que cree un ejemplo completo dímelo. Por lo pronto con solo el primer código debería funcionar bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general tu idea funciona con los datos que has proporcionado, pero el problema que estás sufriendo es que estás calculado la diferencia de datos entre dos matrices, cuando lo que quieres es averiguar qué datos de una matriz han dejado de existir en otra, que son dos cosas diferentes.

Ejemplo:

- A -> 1, 4, 5
- B -> 2, 4, 7

Diferencia (los que hay en A que no están en B y los que hay en B que no están en A):

**1, 5, 2, 7**

Lo que hay en A que no están en B:

**1, 5**

---

Una forma de llevar a cabo el trabajo sería con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$Todo = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 1112,
        'que' => 'Codigo',
        'idcosa' => 80,
        1 => 129,
        2 => 40,
        3 => 843446300048,
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1113,
        'que' => 'Codigo',
        'idcosa' => 80,
        1 => 36,
        2 => 40,
        3 => 843446300049,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 1114,
        'que' => 'Codigo',
        'idcosa' => 80,
        1 => 129,
        2 => 87,
        3 => 843446300050,
    ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => 1115,
        'que' => 'Codigo',
        'idcosa' => 80,
        1 => 36,
        2 => 87,
        3 => 843446300051,
    )
);

$EnFormulario = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 1112,
        'id' => 1112,
        1 => 129,
        'que' => 'Codigo',
        2 => 40,
        'idcosa' => 80,
        3 => 843446300048,
    ),

    1 => array(
        0 => 1113,
        'id' => 1113,
        1 => 36,
        'que' => 'Codigo',
        2 => 40,
        'idcosa' => 80,
        3 => 843446300049,
    )
);

/* Generamos un índice de $EnFormulario */
$formulario = [];
foreach($EnFormulario as $clave => $valor) {
    if (isset($valor['id'])) {
        $formulario[$valor['id']] = true;
    }
}

foreach($Todo as $valor) {
    if (isset($valor['id'])) {
        /* Buscamos en el índice y si no existe el valor lo borramos */
        if (!isset($formulario[$valor['id']])) {
            echo "<p>Borrando {$valor['id']}</p>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Lo ideal es que generaras directamente el índice desde los datos obtenidos y no haciendo un bucle para pasar por ellos.

Una forma de hacerlo sería modificando la obtención de datos así:

```
$Todo = Consulta_Dinamica(
    "Array",
    "*",
    "Direcciones",
    "`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '" . $_POST["art_nuevo"] . "' "
);
/* Generamos directamente $formulario con su índice por 'id' */
$formulario = [];
foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUpColorTalli) {
    $EnFormulario = Consulta_Dinamica(
        "Simple",
        "*",
        "Direcciones",
        "`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '" . $_POST["art_nuevo"] .
            "' AND `1`='" . $DUpColorTalli['tallas'] .
            "' AND `2`='" . $DUpColorTalli['color'] . "' "
    );
    if (isset($EnFormulario['id'])) {
        $formulario[$EnFormulario['id']] = $EnFormulario;
    }
}
/* Ya no hace falta hacer el bucle foreach que generaba los índices a partir de la matriz $EnFormulario */
foreach($Todo as $valor) {
    if (isset($valor['id'])) {
        /* Buscamos en el índice y si no existe el valor lo borramos */
        if (!isset($formulario[$valor['id']])) {
            echo "<p>Borrando {$valor['id']}</p>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que ahora te hagas una mejor idea de cómo generar la matriz con los resultados de la búsqueda usando como índice uno de los campos del resultado.

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido... En la segunda forma de hacerlo simplemente estas guardando en $formulario los id de las cosas que no tienen id definido en mysql ¿no? con lo cual no hace falta la comparación con lo que luego simplemente tengo que borrar todo lo que tenga $formulario. aunque no entiendo muy bien la linea de $formulario[$EnFormulario['id']] = $EnFormulario;

Comment: El segundo ejemplo genera la matriz `$formulario` con índices correspondientes al campo `id`. Es más eficiente comprobar la existencia de un índice que recorrer todos los elementos en busca de una coincidencia. Si no entiendes el cambio te hago el segundo ejemplo completo.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo a ver si lo consigo solo :) Mil gracias en un ratico te digo si lo conseguí.

Comment: Ok, suerte. Por cierto: "no entiendo muy bien la linea de $formulario[$EnFormulario['id']] = $EnFormulario;". Lo que hace esa línea es agregar los datos obtenidos en la consulta usando un índice numérico o de texto asociado al valor que tenga el campo `id`, el contenido es el mismo. Cuando usas $formulario[]` se generan índices numéricos consecutivos, pero eso no nos facilita la tarea de hacer búsquedas por `id` más rápidas cuando comparamos lo que hay en una matriz con la de la otra. Un `isset($formulario[indice])` es óptimo y muchísimo más rápido que una búsqueda secuencial en una matriz.

Comment: Con el primer ejemplo funciona perfecto. Con El Segundo no he sido capaz de hacerlo funcionar, En vez de ponerme los que no existían me ponía los que si existían.

Comment: Te he completado el segundo ejemplo para ponértelo en contexto. Como ves te ahorras todo el bloque `/* Generamos un índice de $EnFormulario */` que generaba una matriz con índice porque creamos la matriz directamente con él, sin usar el operador `[]` que crearía índices de matriz secuenciales.

Answer (score -3):

Para encontrar la diferencia entre dos array con array_diff basta.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php

Si utilizaras array_diff($array1, $array2) te va a devolver los elementos  de 
$array1 que no existen en $array2

Saludos

Comment: Hola, esta respuesta es mas un comentario, hace falta que agregues mas detalles para que se considere una respuesta de calidad. Saludos